# How can I make a C++ program to read predefined files after installation on linux

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf, automake

My project folder has the following structure

```
-Project/
        /src
             -Main.cpp
             -MyReader.cpp
        /headers
             -MyReader.h
        /DataFiles
             -File.dat
             -File1.dat
```

My class `Object.cpp` has a couple of methods which reads from `File.dat` and `File1.dat` and parse the information to Map objects. My problem is that I am using Autotools (in which I'm very very newbie) for generating config and installer files and I don't know how to make all the DataFiles files accessible for the program after installation. The program doesn't work properly because of the code fails when trying to read those files through relative paths. Locally, the program runs perfectly after executing in terminal `make && ./program`.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: relative paths are the devil. Do not forget that at any time the user could `/path/to/executable/program` and run the program from the root of the file system. The relative path will fail horribly and there's pretty much nothing you can do to stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A platform independent way to do this with `Autotools` is using the `$(datadir)` variable to locate the system data directory and work relative to that.

So in your `Makefile.am` file you can create a name like this:

```
myprog_infodir = $(datadir)/myprog

# Set a macro for your code to use
myprog_CXXFLAGS = -DDATA_LOCATION=\"$(datadir)/myprog\"

# This will install it from the development directories
myprog_info_DATA = $(top_srcdir)/DataFiles/File.dat $(top_srcdir)/DataFiles/File1.dat

# make sure it gets in the installation package
extra_DIST = $(top_srcdir)/DataFiles/File.dat $(top_srcdir)/DataFiles/File1.dat
```

Then in your program you should be able to refer to the data like this:

```
std::ifstream ifs(DATA_LOCATION "/File.dat");
```

**Disclaimer:** *Untested code*

Comment: Last question @Galik How can I set DATA_LOCATION only when `sudo make install` is executed. I would like to be able to use another location when `make` is typed. Is this possible?

Comment: When you run the `configure` script you can set the data directory using the `--datadir=DIR` switch. Try running `./configure --help` for other information on varying the build.

Comment: Ok, but what I want is to make available DATA_LOCATION only when running `sudo make install`. Otherwise, the program uses the path specified in the source code. (.cpp) when `make` runs.

Comment: @VladimirTepes It will always be fixed when compiling this way. Another option might be to create a configure script that your program can read and store the chosen location in that? It depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one method and will give my example here:

In my Makefile.am

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -D MATRIXDIR="\"$(pkgdatadir)/matrix\""

nobase_dist_pkgdata_DATA = matrix/AAcode.txt  \
matrix/BLOSUM50 matrix/BLOSUM70.50 matrix/BLOSUM100 matrix/BLOSUM50.50 \
matrix/BLOSUM75 matrix/BLOSUM100.50 matrix/BLOSUM55 matrix/BLOSUM75.50 \
... more not shown
```

I put quite some number of datafiles in the matrix directory, just show a few of them.  In my source file, I simply use the macro MATRIXDIR:

```
scorematrix.cpp:string MatrixScoreMethod::default_path=MATRIXDIR;
```

This seems to work well for me.  You can use other versions of the data automake variable, such as dist_data_DATA instead of pkgdata.  It is a good idea to use pkgdata this way your data will not be mixed with other packages. The nobase_ is to tell automake not to strip the matrix directory during install. Those escaped double quotes seems to be needed for string type so that you don't get compiler errors.